# How should you test if a variable is a value type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a few places where I have a generic type parameter that is not limited to class (or struct), and when I try to compare variables of that type against `null`, Resharper underlines it, complaining that I may be comparing a value type to `null` (a valid objection, to be sure). Is there an accepted way of checking if a variable is a value type before comparing against null?

For example:

```
public TObject MyProperty { get; set; }

...
private void SomeMethod()
{
    if(MyProperty == null) //Warning here
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I've been doing `if(!(MyProperty is ValueType) && MyProperty)`--is that valid? It doesn't get rid of the warning, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: If you end up _wanting_ to compare a Value-type to null, you have deeper problems.

Comment: In this case you don't need to do the check - the equality will return false if MyProperty is a value type.  The compiler will write code to convert MyProperty to a Nullable<TObject> first.  Still the warning is valid as it suggests you're being lax in your typing.

Comment: If you know the type beforehand you know if it can be null, so the test is unnecessary. If your method is generic it will not generate a warning. So the test is unnecessary too. And finally there are nullable value types.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Really? So how would you manage something like this:

A query builder, which takes a generic type that can be of any type--reference or value--and a SQL conversion method which needs to put out a BETWEEN clause, but will throw an exception if either of the operands of the BETWEEN clause is null? Yes, you could use `object` instead of a type parameter, but what if you want to constrict the operands to be of the same type?

Basically, I think there are definitely valid use cases for comparing a variable to null when you don't know whether it's value- or reference-type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you want to do in the case that it is a value type?  sometimes I will do:

```
public void DoStuff<T> (T variable)
{
    if(variable == default(T))
        ...  // true if null or 0 in the case of a value type
}
```

Or:

```
if( typeof(T).IsValueType )
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx).

Comment: I like the `default(T)` way of doing it.

Comment: I want the comparison to return false if the object is a value type (basically, these are cases in which I want to do some specific logic if the object is a reference type and is null, but the rest of the code doesn't care). It sounds like the compiler will take care of that already--I wasn't sure how it treated such a situation.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I didn't benchmark the two solutions, that but which one would be faster, and why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection, but it's slow and should be avoided:

```
bool isValueType = typeof(TObject).IsValueType;
```

Does your generic method really have a need to pass both reference and value types as its type parameter?

Comment: Small 'typo' you had there :)

Comment: I think it should be either `typeof(TObject)` or `MyProperty.GetType()`.

Comment: @leppie: fixed thanks, you are both right

Answer (score 1):

You could just compare the type:

```
if (MyProperty.GetType() == typeof(...))
{

}
```

You are getting a warning because `MyProperty` isn't assigned to.

Comment: `MyProperty.GetType()` will throw a NullReferenceException if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(T t)
{
    return ((Object)t == null);
}
```